# Get NSParagraphStyle of UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nsparagraphstyle

Is there any way to get the `NSParagraphStyle` of an `UILabel` instead of creating a new instance and settings every attribute?

Comment: If it has a `attributedText`, you can enumerate and retrieve the first one found.

Comment: Enumerate what?

Comment: enumerate the `NSParagraphAttributeName` of the attributedText.

Comment: What property to enumerate on?

Comment: `NSAttributedString *attributedString = myLabel.attributedText; [attributedString enumerateAttribute: NSParagraphAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length]) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop){NSParagraph *paragraph = value;})];` ?

Comment: I see, enumerate usually means a kind of loop like a `for`. Add it as an answer so I can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:` to retrieve the `NSParagraphStyle` on the `attributedText` property of your `UILabel` object:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = myLabel.attributedText;

[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                             inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
                             options:0
                          usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

                       NSParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = value; // Do what you want with paragraph
}];
```

The code is not tested (may not compile due to some small mistakes), but it should give you the idea behind it.

Comment: For some reason, `value` is always `nil`. Also, I initially wanted to retrieve it from an `UILabel` that doesn't have an `attributedText`.

Comment: Why did you edited my code without reason? Especially with modification which doesn't cause issue (dot syntax vs "square bracklet one"), and you can't put `NSParagraphStyle` as argument of the method, it's a NSString that needs to be there `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`, not a class name.

Comment: Because `length` is a property, not a method, and is more readable this way. The other edits were because the code didn't compile, and the `NSParagraphStyle` was a mistake.